# UItableView scroll unexplained crash (UITableViewCellScrollView _systemGestureStateChanged)

Tags: ios, tableview

I seem to have a very odd issue.

I have a `tableView` (inside a `UIViewController`) that is loaded from a storyboard. The cells are pretty complex, but it works fine. Cells are loaded from the storyboard too as prototype cells.

Whenever I push a view (the same of o different on), I pop (so I come back to the initial controller) and I try to scroll the tableView (simulator and device), the app crahses without any warning, log, or whatsoever.

There seems to have no visible issue, but when I activate all diagnostics, I get this :

When I print out the address of the error, it seems to be linked to UITableViewCellScrollView :

```
-[UITableViewCellScrollView _systemGestureStateChanged:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xd1d40e30
```

If I change the cells to standard cells, I get the same issue.

I'm using https://github.com/ivanbruel/IBScrollViewFloatingHeader but its deactivation does nothing.
I'm using https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSDynamicsDrawerViewController but its deactivation has no result.

I even managed to reproduce it when scrolling back/forth very fast with basic UItableViewCells.

I'm totally stuck here. Any help would be much much appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT : I tried to put everything more clearly with the latest informations :)

Comment: The problem seems like memory trampling.  Somehow your code is trying to call the function `systemGestureStateChanged` on an object that it has a reference to, but that object no longer exists and was replaced by an instance of `NSDictionaryI`.  Zombies might be able to detect the problem if you profile.

Comment: I enabled NSZombiesEnable, but I had no luck. I just updated the issue with a kinda zombie behavior though I do see how this is possible :-/. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your device will have a crash log on it (even if it doesn't show when debugging).  Find that and post it.

Comment: that's the thing : there is nothing useful in the crash log. I'll post it right away.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Use zombies?

Comment: it's a sort of zombie though enabling zombies did not help.

Comment: Show us your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. By the way, that crash log isn't symbolicated, and is pretty useless that way.

Comment: Your crash log is not symbolicated.  You need to re-symbolicate it, then it will be useful.  See what you can do.

Comment: I know but it does not resymbolicate, no matter what I do ;-/
I posted the code, but I don't think it's related to cells, I already tried to add breakpoints inside cellForRowAtindexPath, that was my first guess
It really seems to behave like if the tableView was release somewhere in the code and that scrolling sends the message to a no more existing tableView :-/

Comment: But as you can see in the crashlog, there are no lines related to my code directly (I think that's why it does not seem symbolicated)

Comment: can you show the code when you are setting the gesture to the tableScrollView? R u using ARC on this project?

Comment: I don't set any gesture on the tableView. It's ARC and uses storyboards

Comment: Try to check on the Storyboard if each outlet only connected with 1 property, that might be the problem

Comment: good idea, but nope, it's only connected once :(

Comment: check your UITableViewCell and TableView, r u using weak, retain, or strong?

Comment: I just saw that is points out to UITableViewCellScrollView, which is an iOS7 new view inside the cells. Maybe it can be helpful ?

Comment: try to allocate and not setting it to nil
FeedTableViewCell *cell = [FeedTableViewCell alloc]init];
FeedTableViewCell *cell = nil;

Comment: still gets the same issue :(